# How does APT decide which "binary-" directories to look in?

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, apt, raspbian

Using a Raspberry Pi, I am trying to use a newer version of puppet than the provided 2.7 by adding the puppetlabs repository, which has no 'binary-armhf' folders. (For non-Raspbian users - Raspbian is wheezy-based.) This repository is structured as follows:

- dists

  - hardy

    - ...
  - ...
  - wheezy

    - dependencies

      - ...
    - main

      - binary-all
      - binary-amd64
      - binary-i386
      - source

My expectation is that APT should, on seeing that there is no `main/binary-armhf` directory (in the `wheezy/Release` file), fall back to `main/binary-all`; instead, `apt-get update` prints an error

```
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.puppetlabs.com/dists/wheezy/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

and `apt-cache madison puppet` does not show any binary packages (only source) as available for installation from apt.puppetlabs.com.

From inspecting other packages correctly installed from the default repository, apt on this platform seems to accept 'all' as an architecture for packages that happen to be listed in a `binary-armhf/Packages` file; however, it seems not to accept 'all' as an architecture when looking for a `Packages(.gz)` to download.

To the actual questions:

1. Are there any clients that actually consider their own architecture to be 'all'?
2. Is there a way to configure APT to check `main/binary-all` in addition to `main/binary-$native_arch`? EDIT: There is (using the `deb [arch=all]` in sources.list) - but it's not clear if this is always safe to do. (e.g. if you say `[arch=i386]`, does it make your system think it can install `i386` packages, or will it just fetch the Packages list?).
3. If neither of the above answers is yes, what's the intended utility of a `main/binary-all` release that no clients will actually fetch?

Comment: Having accepted the answer: can you confirm that `[arch=all]` does the trick? Would be a good hint for other affected users :)

Comment: Ah - yes I can. Adding to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Guess you just saved the day of someone asking about that on IRC. Now have to get word to him, if he enters the channel again :)

Comment: Just had a similar problem, apt-get wanting to get packages for i386 architecture. I found this solution: dpkg --remove-architecture i386

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apt printed only warning (`W:`), not error. The `Release` file contains only checksums of other index files. `binary-all` is for architecture independent packages, like those written in perl or python.

I suppose the `Packages` file should correctly specify where to look for binary package. I have chacked it and the `puppet` package seems to be specified in `binary-all/Packages` file. But the main problem is probably that aptitude doesn't allow you to use any packages from repository which doesn't know your architecture. Maybe empty `binary/arm-hf/Packages` file + mention of `arm-hf` in `Architectures: i386 amd64 all` in `Release` file would suffice. Until then, you have to manually download the `.deb` files and install them using `dpkg -i`.

Now your 3 questions: I would say that no client has architecture "all" by default. APT does check also the "binary-all" directory, but it probably cannot live without repository which knows its architecture. Speaking of that, the workaround with `[arch=all]` should work, but I would not try it with anything else than "all".

Here is a document about the format of debian repositories [Debian Repository Format](http://wiki.debian.org/RepositoryFormat).

Comment: For the curious [arch=all] definitely works; I cannot confirm that [arch=ANYTHING_ELSE] is safe.